# Tkinter use of function and class

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, window

so this is my class which is Login_Window

```
class Login_Window:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.window.state('zoomed')
        self.window.resizable(0, 0)
        self.window.title('Login and Registration Page')

        # Window Icon Photo
        icon = PhotoImage(file='images\\pic-icon.png')
        self.window.iconphoto(True, icon)

        LoginPage = Frame(window)
        RegistrationPage = Frame(window)

        for frame in (LoginPage, RegistrationPage):
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        def show_frame(frame):
            frame.tkraise()

        show_frame(LoginPage)


# ========== DATABASE VARIABLES ============
  
    Email = StringVar()
    FullName = StringVar()
    Password = StringVar()
    ConfirmPassword = StringVar()
```

why cant i call the show_frame, registrationPage, LoginPage is it because of the data variables?

```
# ==================== LOGIN PAGE =====================================================================================

design_frame1 = Listbox(LoginPage, bg='#0c71b9', width=250, height=100, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
design_frame1.place(x=0, y=0)

design_frame2 = Listbox(LoginPage, bg='#1e85d0', width=250, height=100, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
design_frame2.place(x=1000, y=0)

design_frame3 = Listbox(LoginPage, bg='#1e85d0', width=100, height=33, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
design_frame3.place(x=450, y=250)

design_frame4 = Listbox(LoginPage, bg='#f8f8f8', width=100, height=33, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
design_frame4.place(x=1000, y=250)  # 106 #676

# ====== Email ====================
```

this is the function page.

```
def page():
    window = Tk()
    Login_Window(window)
    window.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    page()
```

since the beginning i didnt create a class before i started the window frame page i just use this code and then i decided to create a class so that it will be cleaner as my second page is created by a class as well. how can i solve this, thanks

```
window = Tk()
window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.state('zoomed')
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.title('Login and Registration Page')

# Window Icon Photo
icon = PhotoImage(file='images\\pic-icon.png')
window.iconphoto(True, icon)

LoginPage = Frame(window)
RegistrationPage = Frame(window)

for frame in (LoginPage, RegistrationPage):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


def show_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make the function a proper method (indent it to the same level of `__init__` and include the `self` parameter). You can then call it with `self` inside the class, and with the instance outside of the class

```
class Login_Window:
    def __init__(self, window):
        ...
        for frame in (LoginPage, RegistrationPage):
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(LoginPage)

    def show_frame(self, frame):
        frame.tkraise()
```

From outside the class you need a reference to the instance so that  you can call the method on the instance.

```
lw = Login_Window(window)
...
lw.show_frame(LoginPage)
```